# Is there a way to tell JSON that a number is Long instead of Integer?

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman, long-integer

I have a table called "sector" which ID is Long instead of Integer. When I send a request from postman where I say that i want the entities from certain table where "anotherEntity.idSector = 1" it will give me an error.

Anfter several try/error I just discovered that this "1" is an integer for Postman, so when it gets to Java it gives me an error because expects a Long value.

So, is there a way to tell JSON that the value is a Long number? If it was a double, i would replace the "1" by "1.0" and it'd do, but with Long numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't "tell JSON" anything, it's just an encoding format. Like JavaScript, JSON has no integers, no longs, no floats and no doubles.

It has numbers: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-6

If you need more integer precision than JSON's number type provides, you would typically encode the number as a string. This is generally a good policy for fields like record IDs which are *incidentally* numeric, rather than semantically numbers (ie, you'll never perform numeric operations on them like addition or division).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to answer...So apart from "asking" the Map<String, Object> i receive if it has a key called "idSector", is there another workaround?

Comment: @Calfa Best practice is to treat IDs in JSON as opaque strings. Maybe they're Longs, maybe they're UUIDs, maybe they're Base58... just "this is a string; match it but don't parse it".

Comment: That would be an answer i'd certainly mark. Please don't hesitate to convert that comment into an answer. It's frustrating to see how more experienced programmers are downvoting my question because, i guess, they consider it stupid. The issue, tho, is real, despite i'm a newbie programmer but hey! I try my best!